# Given the sequence {39, 174, 441, 876, 1515, ....}, find the generating function

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

It seems that there is a lot of differentiation and right shifting in this equation but I do not know which comes first. Here's what I've done:

> Initial function (Known function): {1,1,1,1,1,...} = 1x<sup>0</sup> + 1x<sup>1</sup> + 1x<sup>2</sup>+ 1x<sup>3</sup> + 1x<sup>4</sup> + ... = 1/(1-x)

(differentiating)

> func. 1: {1,2,3,4,5,...} = 0 + 1 + 2x+ 3x<sup>2</sup> + 4x<sup>3</sup> + 5x<sup>4</sup> +... = 1/(1-x)<sup>2</sup>

.... fourth round of differentiating:

> func. 4: {6,24,60,120,210,...} =  6 + + 24x+ 60x<sup>2</sup> + 120x<sup>3</sup> + 210x<sup>4</sup> +... = 3/(1-x)<sup>4</sup>

I tried Right Shifting afterwards which produced:

> {0,6,24,60,120,210,...} = 0 + 6x + 24x<sup>2</sup> + 60x<sup>3</sup> + 120x<sup>4</sup> + 210x<sup>5</sup> +... = 3x/(1-x)<sup>4</sup>

**Need to find: {39,174,441,876,1515,...} = ?(function) = ?(Generating Function}**

Wolframalpha suggests that the generating function is 3(7x<sup>2</sup> - 6x - 13)/(x-1)<sup>4</sup>

Can anyone advise me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: This is not clear.  What is the sequence you are trying to generate?  You give us a few terms in the header, I guess, but what is the general term?

Comment: In the question, the sequence is {39, 174, 441, 876, 1515,...} and the generating function is to be found. The initial function i have given is what is known and what is used to get to the generating function. **Edit to add** the equation that each function equates to is what I'm interested in, i.e, the generating function.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are we meant to guess at the general term?  You must have left off some pertinent information.  Can you write out more terms of the sequence?  If so, how are you getting them?

Comment: @lulu We are meant to find the generating function by using 4 general operations: **Scaling** (Multiplying the function by a constant throughout), **Right Shifting** (Multiplying by x throughout), **Addition** (Adding two functions that you have found/ know) and **Differentiation** (Differentiating the function). We use some/all of these operations until you have found a function whose coefficients are 39,174,441,876,1515,...etc. The way to go about it is to establish a pattern but that is where I'm having difficulty.

Comment: This is very unclear.  I think, but I'm not at all sure, that you are saying something like this:  we start with $f(x)=\sum x^n=\frac 1{1-x}$.  You may operate on this function finitely often using the operations you indicated and take linear combinations of the functions thus obtained.  You would like to do this in such a way that the first few terms happen to match the given sequence, of which you are only given the first five terms.  Is that right?

Comment: @lulu correct! Sorry for not providing clarity. Each operation is performed on the previous function. For example, we differentiate the initial function to get func. 2 then we perform some operation on func. 2 to get the next function and so on.

Comment: Well, it's an odd sort of exercise.  Seems like guess work mostly...it should be very easy to verify Wolfram Alpha's expression, if it is correct and that verification certainly constitutes a valid proof (though I can see where it is a bit unsatisfying).  I can't immediately see a good way to attack it....I suppose you could set it up as a set of simultaneous linear equations but it would be fairly ugly.

Comment: @lulu it mostly definitely is. One way to go is to also try to simplify the sequence to a simpler sequence. I would try to verify Wolfram Alpha's expression and also try your suggestion. Thank you :)

Comment: The sequence satisfies the cubic polynomial $39 + 81 n + 48 n^2 + 6 n^3$ (indexing at 0) or $3 n + 30 n^2 + 6 n^3$ (indexing at 1). I'm not sure how you're supposed to guess this by simply differentiating $(1 - x)^{-1}$ and comparing, however. Also, if it does satisfy a cubic polynomial, they should really give more than 5 terms.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Can you give me a brief rundown of how you came to your conclusion or some source? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you calculate the forward differences: $174 - 39, 441 - 174, 876 - 441, 1515 - 876$ then calculate the forward differences of the forward differences and the forward differences of those forward differences, you get $36, 36$. Because the third forward differences are constant, we can conclude that the sequence can be generated by a degree 3 polynomial. The idea is that taking forward differences reduces the degree by $1$, for example for $n^2$ the forward difference is $(n + 1)^2 - n^2 = 2n + 1$ is a linear function.

Comment: You can work out a polynomial from its forward differences (it's a good exercise). Or you can ask [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+for+%7B39,+174,+441,+876,+1515%7D)

Comment: @TrevorGunn wow, okay thanks very much. Made it so much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $f_0=\{1,1,1,1,1,...\}=\frac 1{1-x}$

Differentiating gives $f_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,...\}=\frac 1{(1-x)^2}$. This is a linear sequence.

Not given, but differentiating again gives $f_2=\{2,6,12,20,30...\}=\frac 2{(1-x)^3}$. Note that this is a quadratic sequence with second difference 2.

Differentiating again gives $f_3=\{6,24,60,120,210...\}=\frac 6{(1-x)^4}$. Note that this is a cubic sequence with third difference 6. Note also that I disagree with you slightly... $\frac d{dx}\left (\frac 2{(1-x)^3}\right)=\frac 6{(1-x)^4}$, not $\frac 3{(1-x)^4}$

We are given $g=\{39, 174, 441, 876, 1515, ...\}$.

The terms form a cubic sequence with third difference 36. They can therefore be written as a linear combination of $f_0$, $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$.

Start by subtracting $\frac {36}6 f_3$

$g-6f_3=\{39, 174, 441, 876, 1515, ...\}-\{36,144,360,720,1260,...\}$

which gives $g_1=\{3,30,81,156,255,...\}$

The terms form a quadratic sequence with common difference $24$ so subtract $\frac {24}2 f_2$

$g_1-12f_2=\{3, 30, 81, 156, 255, ...\}-\{24,72,144,240,360,...\}$

which gives $g_2=\{-21,-42,-63,-84,-105,...\}$

We can see that $g_2=-21f_1$

Since we have $g-6f_3-12f_2=-21f_1$,

we can say $g=6f_3+12f_2-21f_1$

Thus $g=\frac {6 \times 6}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{12 \times 2}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{21 \times 1}{(1-x)^2}$

$g=\frac {36}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{24(1-x)}{(1-x)^4}-\frac{21(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^4}$

$g=\frac {36+24-24x-21+42x-21x^2}{(1-x)^4}$

$g=\frac {39+18x-21x^2}{(1-x)^4}$

$g=\frac {3(13+6x-7x^2)}{(1-x)^4}$